# return pandas DF column with the number of days elapsed between index and today's date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dF that has dates as its index, and I would like to add a new column 'delta' that shows the number of days between the date in the index and todays date.

I have:

```
dF['today'] = '2015-01-30'
dF['today'] = pd.to_datetime(dF['today'])
dF['tvalue']= dF.index
dF['delta'] = (dF['tvalue'] - dF['today'])
```

Obviously, this is not working. Any feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas methods to solve the problem right away.

Consider e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3]}
      , index = [pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-30', '2015-01-29','2015-01-25'])] )
```

that is

```
                 A
     2015-01-30  1
     2015-01-29  2
     2015-01-25  3
```

then you define

```
today = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-30')
```

so that you can finally calculate

```
(df.index - today).days

 array([ 0, -1, -5])
```

which clearly can be added as a further column.

---

Finally, the date of today can be obtained automatically by doing

```
today = pd.datetime.today()
```

Comment: `.days` does not work for me, instead `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` works.

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
import datetime

def ymd2epoch(y, m, d):
    t = datetime.datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0).timetuple()
    return int(time.mktime(t))

def yyyymmdd2epoch(s):
    ymd = map(int, s.split('-'))
    return ymd2epoch(ymd[0], ymd[1], ymd[2])

def ymd_todaydiff(ymd):
    seconds_diff = int(time.time()) - yyyymmdd2epoch(ymd)
    daydiff = seconds_diff / (24*60*60)
    return daydiff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    for ymd in sys.argv[1:]:
        sys.stdout.write("DayDiff(%s) = %d\n" % 
                         (ymd, ymd_todaydiff(ymd)))
    sys.exit(0)
```

*running it:*

```
$ ./daydiff.py 2015-01-01 2015-01-29 2015-01-30 2014-01-30
DayDiff(2015-01-01) = 30
DayDiff(2015-01-29) = 2
DayDiff(2015-01-30) = 1
DayDiff(2014-01-30) = 366
```